# how to use the &command in SQL insert into statement?

Tags: mysql, database, sql

what is the syntax of the insert into statement wherein SQL prompts for input?
like for example, if I have attributes "name" and "age" in a student table and I write an insert query , SQL will prompt "enter name:"...."enter age:"....
I used to use this in college but completely forgot . all I remember is that we used '&' somewhere in the query syntax.
Thanks

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: You have tagged this question [meta-tag:mysql], and in MySQL Server, this is not a capability that exists.  Are you thinking about [prompting for SQL query values in Microsoft Access](http://https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Use-parameters-to-ask-for-input-when-running-a-query-c2806d3d-d500-45a8-8507-ec6af351b6ed?ui=en-US&rs=en-ZA&ad=ZA), perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

There are not a way to do an MySQL query asking for values in a prompt or windows natively.

That you ask are specials functionabilities given by an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)

Example:

- Toad
- MySQL workbench
- HeidiSQL
- Aqua
- Etc...

Answer (score 0):

To print a statement do the following (changing your text of course):

```
select 'What is your name?' AS '';
```

To enter text into said database then you must run an insert - this will depend on your schema.

```
INSERT INTO customer (customerID,customer_name) values (1, 'Joe Bloggs');
```

What you're talking about with your `&` sign is the connection string like:

```
mysql -u username -ppassword -D dbname -ss -n -q |&
```